# Soma dos valores na View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp

Gostaria de realizar uma simples soma de uns valores na minha View.
Tentei realizar dessa forma:

```
@foreach (ReceitaIndexVM receita in Model)
{
    decimal Total = 0;
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
        <div class="card bg-info text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-title">Total de Receitas</h6>
                @{

                    int cont = receita.Id.ToString("C2").Count();
                    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++)
                    {
                        Total += receita.Valor;
                    }


                }
                <h2 class="lead">@Total</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Mas fica com este resultado:
[image: Resultado]

Coloquei até uma Count do @receita.Id e ele traz o valor de 7. O que estou realizando errado?

Podem me auxiliar?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você poderia fazer simplesmente o seguinte:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
    <div class="card bg-info text-white">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">Total de Receitas</h6>
            <h2 class="lead">@Model.Sum(x => x.Valor)</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pelo que entendi o `Model` da sua página já é uma lista, então você pode fazer o somatório usando `Linq` normalmente.

Usando `<h2 class="lead">@Model.Sum(x => x.Valor)</h2>` ao invés do `foreach` e o `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Nesta parte do código você está iterando, mas não está passando o `index` 
para o objeto:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++){
    Total += receita.Valor;
}
```

Você pode fazer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++){
    Total += receita[i].Valor;
}
```

Ou:

```
receita.foreach(item=>{
Total += item.Valor}){
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Filipe, mas ele acusa este erro:

Error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ReceitaIndexVM'